# Why does one select Scala type members with a hash instead of a dot?

Tags: scala, syntax, type-systems

In Scala, the syntax for selecting a type from a class is different from that of selecting anything else from a class. In that the former uses a hash as the selection operator instead of a dot. Why is that?

Example: If we have a class like so...

```
class Example {
    type Foo = String
}
```

Why do we select the type from the class like this...

```
val example:Example#Foo = "1"
```

instead of like this?

```
val example:Example.Foo = "1"
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`Example#Foo` is called a *type projection* and will match any type `Foo` of any enclosing instance of type `Example`. If you write a type `Example.Foo`, the compiler will look for the *value* (and not *type*) called `Example` and will refer to its enclosing `Foo` type only. This is often used in the context of singleton objects.

For instance:

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  val EnumValue = Value
}

val e: MyEnum.Value = MyEnum.EnumValue
```

If Scala used `.` for type projections, this would lead to confusion because the preceding identifier could be interpreted either as a type or as a value… Hence the `#`. Note that, as @kassens writes, Java *only* has type projections in that respect.

Comment: Note that Java only has type projections. The type system of Java can not guarantee that a class returns an instance of an inner class *of the same instance* (same outer instance: `this.Inner` vs. any outer instance: `Outer#Inner`).