# Scala: Constraining a generic type parameter to a type within another parameter

Tags: generics, scala, bounds

I'm still trying to grasp the Scala language, so please bear with me and all my questions.

Can I reference an abstract type from one type parameter in the bound for another? For instance, is there a way in which the following code can be made to work? The essence of what I'm trying to achieve here is that the KEY for the MAP parameter of C should be the SomeType of the parameter T.

```
trait T1 { 
    type SomeType;
}

trait MyMap[KEY, VALUE] { ... }


class C { 
  def m[T <: T1, MAP <: MyMap[T.SomeType, Int]] { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [type projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676048/why-does-one-select-scala-type-members-with-a-hash-instead-of-a-dot):

```
def m[T <: T1, MAP <: MyMap[T#SomeType, Int]]
```