# Overriding abstract type does not work with control abstraction

Tags: scala, traits, abstract-type

This question follows the one in [Cake pattern with overriding abstract type don't work with Upper Type Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213395/cake-pattern-with-overriding-abstract-type-dont-work-with-upper-type-bounds). I want to override the abstract type in trait with `<:`. The previous links gives the solution which consists in changing the order of linearization by writting `this: Cake with S` in trait S. However, I added a control abstraction named `control` in the following code. I want to call the method `t` in it.

```
trait A {
  def ping = println("ping")
}

trait Cake {
  type T
}

trait S { this: Cake with S =>
  type T <: A with S
  def t: T
  def s = println("test")
  // def control(c: =>T): T = c // compile
  // def control(c: =>T): T = c.s // does not compile
  def control(c: =>T): T = c.t // does not compile
  t.ping
  t.s
}
```

But, this code results in a compilation error that I can't explain

```
 found   : S.this.T#T
 required: S.this.T
         def control(c: =>T): T = c.t
                                    ^
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def control(c: =>T): T
```

Has return type `S#T`. Clearly, `c` has type `T` as well. Hence, returning `c` in:

```
def control(c: =>T): T = c
```

compiles, while returning `c.s` does not compile because `s` has return type of `Unit`.
`c.t` does not compile because it has return type of `S#T#T`.

Thus, the following will compile:

```
def control(c: =>T): T#T = c.t
```

As the specifics behind everything that is happening here are a bit non-trivial in general, I suggest you google "type projection" and "path dependent types" for more information.

Essentially what is happening is `c` has type `T`, where `T <: A with S`, so we know `T` must have all of `S`'s members, one of which is defined as `def t: T`. But this `T` is not necessarily the same as our `T`, so it does not conform when we call `c.t` in your example. What we want is the `T` of type `T` (or equivalently, `T`'s `T`, or the `T` of our type member `T`). Here `T#T` indicates exactly what we want.

Comment: Also see this stack overflow questions for more info on type projections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676048/why-does-one-select-scala-type-members-with-a-hash-instead-of-a-dot.