# Scala syntax how to create an instance of a nested case class

Tags: scala, inner-classes, case-class

Considering this typedef:

```
case class Outer(someVal: Int) {
  case class Inner(someOtherVal: Int)
}
```

how do I construct an object of type `Inner`, (i.e. how do I write the valid scala syntax)?

I want the `Inner` to scoped to `Outer` to avoid name clashes with different instances of Outer in the same package.

Comment: Are you sure you want Inner to be *instance* class, rather than *class* class (in Java you write *static* for the later)? If not you have to define Inner in companion, otherwise `val x = Outer(1); x.Inner(2)` will work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inner is in scope of an outer instance.
So, you can write something like that :

```
val res = new Outer(4)
val res2 = new res.Inner(2)
```

But, i don't think it's what you want.
To avoid name clashes, you can use package, it is made for that.

edit :

You can also define Inner in companion object of Outer, like om-nom-nom said :

```
case class Outer(someVal : Int)
object Outer {
  case class Inner(otherVal : Int)
}

val res = Outer(5)
val in = Outer.Inner(6)
```

Comment: See also [*type projection*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676048/why-does-one-select-scala-type-members-with-a-hash-instead-of-a-dot)